# H2 Tags in ty-product-list__item-name CS-Cart

Tags: css, cs-cart

I am trying to modify `div` class specially `ty-product-list__item-name` in my template file so it display as `h2` tags.

The class is presents in my template file something like this

```
<div class="ty-product-list__info">
<div class="ty-product-list__item-name">
    {assign var="name" value="name_$obj_id"}
    {$smarty.capture.$name nofilter}
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `h2` tags ?

Comment: <h2 class="ty-product-list__item-name"> I tried to do this  is that good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working just fine with the following statement

`<h2 class="ty-product-list__item-name">
    {assign var="name" value="name_$obj_id"}
    {$smarty.capture.$name nofilter}
</h2>`

Perfect